# Disabled contribution page and recurring transactions

Tags: contributions, contribution-page, recurring-contributions, iats

Can recurring contributions originally set up with "Contribution Page A" still occur if Page A is subsequently disabled?

Civi 4.6 LTS with iATS payments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - absolutely - the recurring series only stops if its status is switch to: cancelled or the number of installments have been completed (both are native CiviCRM behaviour).